# openUI5 - Why is my event TableRow getBindingContext() undefined?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to write a simple table with a `RowAction` to delete rows.
I've got the table bound successfully to a `JSONModel` (named **sites**). I've attached a function to the `press` event of the `RowActionItem` and can see it's being called successfully.

However when the function is called, I can see the `sap.ui.base.Event` object passed into the event function has some data (for example, I can get the `TableRow` and correctly see which index was to be deleted), but the row data binding context is always undefined.

I've looked at the sample here: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.RowAction/preview

Two things of note:

1- I have no idea what using a variable for the event function and then using `bind(this)` on it does.  Explanations more then welcomed.

```
var fnPress = this.handleActionPress.bind(this);
```

2- My own table & RowAction/RowActionItem(s) are declared in XML in the view (another one which gave me some challenge!).  It looks like this:

```
<t:Table 
    id="clientsTable"
    rows="{path:'sites>/data', templateShareable: false}"
    selectionMode="Single"
    selectionBehavior="RowOnly"
    visibleRowCountMode="auto"
    ariaLabelledBy="title"
    rowSelectionChange="onSelectionChange"
    rowActionCount="1" >
    <t:toolbar>
        <m:Toolbar>
            <m:content>
                <core:Icon
                    src="sap-icon://customer-and-contacts"
                    size="1.5rem"
                    color="#346187"/>
                <m:Title id="clientsTableTitle" text="Client(s)" />
                <m:ToolbarSpacer/>
                <m:Button 
                    id="addClient" 
                    icon="sap-icon://add" 
                    tooltip="Add Client"
                    press="onAddClientPressed" />
                <m:Button 
                    id="exportClients" 
                    icon="sap-icon://action" 
                    tooltip="Export Client(s)" />
            </m:content>
        </m:Toolbar>
    </t:toolbar>

    <t:columns>
        <t:Column width="18rem">
            <m:Label text="System Unique Id" />
            <t:template>
                <m:Text text="{sites>systemGUID}"/>
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
        <t:Column width="15rem">
            <m:Label text="Client Name" />
            <t:template>
                <m:Input value="{sites>name}"/>
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
        <t:Column width="22rem">
            <m:Label text="Client Details" />
            <t:template>
                <m:Input value="{sites>description}"/>
            </t:template>
        </t:Column>
    </t:columns>

    <t:rowActionTemplate>
        <t:RowAction>
                <t:RowActionItem 
                    text="Delete Client" 
                    type="Delete"
                    press="onDeleteClientRow" />
        </t:RowAction>
    </t:rowActionTemplate>
</t:Table>
```

And the event function looks like this (straight from the sample):

```
onDeleteClientRow: function(oEvent) {
                jQuery.sap.log.info("Clients.onDeleteClientRow() called");

                var oRow = oEvent.getParameter("row");
                var oItem = oEvent.getParameter("item");

                var oView = this.getView();
                var oName = oView.getModel().getProperty("name", oRow.getBindingContext());

                MessageToast.show("Action " + (oItem.getText() || oItem.getType()) + " pressed for client: " + oName);  
}
```

And a screenshot:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxdDK.png)

I've tried to declare eveything as code as in the sample as well without success either.  What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the binding context of clicked item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556515/how-to-get-the-binding-context-of-clicked-item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between sample's coding and your's - is that your's one uses the named model to bind rows.
This means that in order to get the binding context, you have to pass the model name parameter.

```
var sName = oView.getModel().getProperty("name", oRow.getBindingContext("sites"));
```

or much shorter:

```
var sName = oRow.getBindingContext("sites").getObject("name");
```

Here is an API for [getBindingContext](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#getBindingContext) and [getObject](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html#getObject) methods.

Comment: Andril, **many thanks**... thinking about it that makes sense.  Got confused as I expected that `oRow.getBindingContext()` would simply return something since the table was bound to the sites model (without explicitly having to pass it as an argument since there is only one).  Bad assumption on my part it seems.

Comment: Also, I had looked at the API documentation for `getBindingContext` and that also seemed to point in that direction... "_If the object does not have a binding context set on itself and has no own model set, it will use the first binding context defined in its parent hierarchy._"

Comment: I agree that it is not a user friendly approach that you have to pass the name of the model but if you think upfront, while your app is getting bigger and your view is extending by extra content, you possibly would introduce more models in the upper hierarchy of controls, so that your rows will also inherit that. And without having to explicitly specify the model's name, your existent coding will be broken, because ui5 has no ide which model's context you want to get. I suppose this is a reason of that.